# jQuery drag event doesn't seem to have deltaX property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, drag

I am trying to create my own slider plugin with jQuery and [this library for the drag event](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag). However, on callback for the event, the deltaX-property doesn't seem to occur, which is really weird since it exists in the documentation. I am using version 2.2 of the library. I am using the library like this:

```
$('#myelement').bind('drag',function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

Does anyone have any experience with the drag event and can help me?
I have also tried using the 'drag' method of the library with the very same result. The deltaX property doesn't exists in the callback.

Comment: I would suggest that you use jQuery UI draggable instead http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is "drag" in bind function callback @params

```
bind(type, callback); 

callback(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY);
```

so;

```
$('#myelement').bind('drag',function(e, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
    console.log(e, delta, deltaX, deltaY);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the props are added as a second argument, so try:

```
$('#myelement').bind('drag',function(e, obj){
    console.log(obj.deltaX);
});
```